# understanding Android drawBitmap() method

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-custom-view

Please someone explain me what exactly happens when canvas.drawBitmap(,,,) is called.When onDraw(Canvas canvas) method is called , a canvas is provided which has an under laying Bitmap.My confusion is, when we call canvas.drawBitmap(otherBitmap,,,) ,what happens to previous Bitmap I mean the original Bitmap which was the the underlying bitmap of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, `drawBitmap()` redraws the specified bitmap at the position you tell it to. If there is currently something present on the canvas it is painted over.

There are different implementations of `drawBitmap()`:

```
drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, float x, float y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)

drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)

drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)

drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)

drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)

drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

This should shed some insight: [drawBitmap()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Canvas.DrawBitmap/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap/Android.Graphics.Rect/Android.Graphics.RectF/Android.Graphics.Paint/).

[Android Canvas Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint))